# Which method get called when i remove a node from parent

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to know which method of child get called when we remove any Node from its
parent.

I created **MyLayer** by extending Layer class and then add my own sprite **MySprite** which extend Sprite class of cocos2d-x framework. I need to decrease a counter when child removed so i need a method which i'd override in my MySprite class.

I use this method to remove.

```
parent->removeChild(child);
```

Here parent is MyLayer and child is MySprite pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the child is running these two methods will be called:

```
child->onExitTransitionDidStart();
child->onExit();
```

If you remove the child with `cleanup = true`(which is the default value), `child->cleanup();` will be also called.

So the best solution for you would be to override `virtual void onExit();` function of the child. And in the overridden method don't forget to call `Node::onExit();` or whatever your superclass will be.

Comment: can i use destructor for  the same ??

Comment: Yes, but the destructor only gets called when the object is deleted, onExit is called when the object is removed from the stage.

Comment: onExit() is better option then destructor because destructor not called immediately when we remove sprite from his parent.